# Is an embankment always man-made?

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible for nature to create an embankment or is the word used exclusively for the result of human activity?

Comment: The definition of embankment can be confusing because you often see the phrase "natural embankment". This should be understood to be an  embankment that looks natural or is made of natural materials. It is not an embankment that is naturally occurring.

Comment: @user814064 See some citations below.

Answer (score 2):

An embankment is man-made, or at least artificial or **deliberately created.** The *em-* prefix indicates that the banking is **being done.**

OED has

> **em-** *prefix*
>   **1. a.** < *em-* + n., ‘to put (something) into or upon what is denoted by the n.’; also ‘to put what is denoted by the n. into’ (something).

For *embankment,* OED has

> 1. The action or process of embanking.
> 2. A mound, bank, or other structure for confining a river, etc. within fixed limits.
> 3. A long earthen bank or mound, *esp.* one raised for the purpose of carrying a road or a railway across a valley.

Note that (2) equates *mound* and *bank* with *structure,* and specifies *fixed limits;* and (3) specifies *raised for a purpose*. All of these indicate it's deliberately made.

A natural riverbank is just a riverbank. An embankment is an artificial riverbank.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, I am somehow emboldened to disagree with the "rule" that the "em-" prefix automatically indicates human activity. Don't ask me what empowers me to do so...maybe I'm just embittered by past experience.

Comment: @JeffSahol That's 1.b. "< em- + n. or adj., with general sense ‘to bring into a certain condition or state’; also (cf. 3) ‘to furnish with something’."

Comment: I'm sorry, Andrew, I should have included the smiley to indicate a joke. One serious objection, though, is that beavers also create embankments, so there's one case when "nature" could have created an "embankment"...not that that is what OP was looking for, I think.

Comment: @JeffSahol whether a beaver or a human, if an animal is involved, I would not consider it "natural". If a structure has been created by the conscious will of a thinking entity (however limited that thinking may be, the beaver _chose_ to build it) as opposed to random processes like erosion or tectonic shift, I would not really call it "natural".

Comment: @terdon May Gaia forgive you for that remark about "random processes".

Comment: @JeffSahol well, if you are involving Gaia, I doubt her bowel movements are _voluntary_. Why should she be any different than the rest of us?:)

Comment: The _em_ (really _en-_ assimilating before a bilabial stop) affix is the old Germanic inchoative/causative, now frozen as either a prefix (_enrage, enjoy, embitter_), or a suffix (_lighten, redden, darken_), or even both (_enlighten, embolden_). The _-ment_ suffix is the one that invites the inference that something is constructed rather than natural. The root _bank_ comes from a natural phenomenon (streams), but an embankment is a banklike thing that has been caused to come about on purpose.

Comment: "Its surface was originally covered with Maple, Birch, and hard Pine-trees, while the low lands on either side are covered with a dense growth of Cedars. I could not help thinking, as I looked upon this **natural embankment**, that it would be easy for an antiquarian to mistake this ridge for a work of art, ..." JOHN S. SPRINGER, 1851 http://www.freefictionbooks.org/books/f/44157-forest-life-and-forest-trees-comprising-winter-ca?start=24

Comment: "Figure 1 highlights some of the geotechnical problems encountered along the embankments of the Bengawan Solo River. Figure 1a shows erosion of the **natural embankment** which runs along one side of the river at this section. It is this eroded material which has been removed from the river bed and used to construct the **man-made embankment** on the other side of the river." [See below]

Comment: *Unsaturated Soils. Advances in Geo-Engineering*: 
Proc. 1st Eur.Conf. E-UNSAT 2008, Durham, UK, 2-4 July 2008 p.446 http://books.google.co.in/books?id=30XRRyrlgZ8C&pg=PA466&lpg=PA466&dq=%22natural+embankment%22&source=bl&ots=sUstYJvVo8&sig=9HEMO8J34_HcyshTxIJfnz33GnY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GiQjUvSHKcTArAfB9IGIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22natural%20embankment%22&f=false

Comment: See also:  **levee** ... "a natural embankment alongside a river, formed by sediment during times of flooding | an artificial embankment alongside a river, built to prevent ..." [encarta​.msn​.com] As well as: http://www.ems-i.com/wmshelp/Terrain_Data/Flood/Delineation/Options/Quadrants.htm   and http://millefiorifavoriti.blogspot.in/2013/07/historic-arkansas-riverwalk-of-pueblo.html